# Don't show inset button border after using TAB

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been looking around everywhere but couldn't find any solutions.

My problem is that when pressing TAB (to move around the form focusing on different controls), the buttons get an ugly inset border that I do not want, there's no option to disable it either.

Note that these inset borders only show on the recently selected/clicked button, not on all **at once**, it displays on whatever button is focused/selected, here are a few examples:

**How I want the button to look (and how it looks before pressing TAB)**
[image: Button before pressing TAB]

**How the button looks after pressing TAB**
[image: Button after pressing TAB]
And that's what all buttons in the form look like when focused until the form is reopened

Any tips? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: That "ugly border" is part of how the Windows operating system works. This allows people without a mouse to know what button has the focus so they can hit the Enter or Spacebar to execute the action. Just keep in mind that it will drive your users crazy if they can't tab around your UI. A lot of people *hate* using the mouse.

Comment: @Andy Yes I know and I am aware of that. I have a different way of visualizing that the button is focused, and that is by changing the button's BackColor (as it does when it's hovered over) when it's focused using Tab, I just didn't want the borders because they do not fit the style of my app, and the border also applied to buttons that have tabbing specifically disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the `ShowFocusCues` return false, although that can be annoying for users who use tabs to navigate.

```
public class MyButton : Button {
    protected override bool ShowFocusCues {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Yes, I agree that it'd be annoying if there was no visualization of the button being focused, but I've explained my intentions in an answer to Andy in the question's comments, and that is changing the button's BackColor when it was focused using Tab.